# Recognition of objects in almost plain background

Tags: image-classification, image-recognition, reference-request

I want to recognize climbing holds in a climbing wall. I thought about implementing my own heuristic algorithm for background detection because it's almost plain, but I was wondering if this kind of task is well known in the community.

Does anybody know the right keywords associated with this? Any research papers or tools that are relevant?

I'm mostly interested in non-supervised learning to avoid having to create a training set for what I think it should be relatively easy but I might be very wrong.

This is a sample image I'd like to classify:
[image]
You can see 4 big holds, 2 small and a number of holes. Ideally I'd detect all of those with bounding boxes but having only the big holds would be good enough.
Any hint on how to approach this would be highly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Try salient object detection.

Comment: @mark It works great. Using this https://github.com/Joker316701882/Salient-Object-Detection I've got https://imgur.com/a/TMHt7lx